# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+n}}=\sqrt n$ has a unique positive solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Prove that for each $n\in \mathbb Z$, $n\ge 1$ there is exactly one $x>0$ satisfying

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx+n}}=\sqrt n$$

Please give me a hint. In fact, after changing the expression, I get the equation:

$$\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{i}{n}}}=1$$

I don't know what next step I should do. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In fact, it should be $\sqrt n$ in the right hand side.

Comment: Just verify that the function on the left is decreasing in $x$ and in $x=0$ is is larger than $\sqrt{n}$ (that may be a bit nontrivial) and for $x\to\infty$ it goes to zero.

Comment: Little remark : "for each $n \in \mathbb{N^*}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note that when $n=1$, $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+\frac{i}{n}}}$$
then $f$ is strictly decreasing and continuous for $x\geq0$ because it is the sum of strictly decreasing and continuous functions.

Moreover $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$ and 
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=1.$$
Hence for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, there is a unique $x_0\geq 0$ such that $f(x_0)=1$.

Comment: In your last sentence, you should replace $>0$ by $\geq 0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $n=1$ gives $x=0$.

Considering
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}+t}} = 1$$

Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}+t}}$ is monotonic decreasing, 
the integral is sandwiched by the upper and lower Riemann sums: $U_{n}<U_{n+1}<1<L_{n+1}<L_{n}$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}+\frac{k}{n}}} < 1 <
  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}+\frac{k}{n}}}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}+\frac{k}{n}}} < 1 <
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n}}}$$

Hence for $n\ge 2$, $\displaystyle \exists x \in \left( \frac{9}{16}-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{9}{16} \right)$ satisfies the equality.

Comment: More precisely, $$x_{n} \approx \frac{9}{16}-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{49}{675n^2}$$ for $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call $f(x)$ the LHS of the equation.

$f(x)$ is defined for  $x>-1/n$

$f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(-3/2)}{(nx+i)^{3/2}}$ is $<0$.

Thus $f$ is a strictly decreasing function with a vertical asymptote with equation $x=-1/n$ and the $x$-axis as horizontal asymptote because $f(x)$ tends to 0 when $x$ tends to $+\infty$.

Therefore $f:(-1/n,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is bijective.

Consequently, there is a unique $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=n$.

Moreover, one can say that  $x_0 \geq 0$ because

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \geq \sqrt{n} \ \ \ (1)$$

(See [this reference](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-prove-frac-1-sqrt-1-+-frac-1-sqrt-2-+-frac-1-sqrt-3-+-ldots-+-frac-1-sqrt-n-ge-sqrt-n-for-natural-numbers-n#!n=12))

Remark: as remarked by @Ng Chung Tak , one has equality in (1) for $n=1$.

Comment: To use derivatives for showing that $f$ is decreasing is an overkill. Further, he wants $x>0$..

Comment: I don't understand your first remark: 1) you would you do without derivative 2) the derivative is so simple .... Concerning your second remark, it is true that I had not seen it : the problem is that $x_0$ can be negative in the examples i have taken...

Comment: You are right, but it still seems to me strange to use deivatives to show that if you increase the denominator, the fraction will decrease.

Comment: @Peter Franek I understand now the meaning of your remark ; you are right, one should always use the less complicated tools to solve a question either mathematical or not. For $x_0$ I had make a mistake : it is always $\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

n=1 would lead to x=0, however the posted constraint on the solution was X > 0.
In that case there exists no solution. Shouldn't the problem be rephrased?

Comment: This should have been a comment to improve the question posed by @user52523 since it is clearly not an answer to the solution.