# Where have I gone wrong in my integral evaluation using summation?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

> $$\int_a^b \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt x}$$ where $a,b>0$

I know how to do it using the formula of course but I want to know the error in my evaluation *through first principles*.

Attempt:

$\int_a^b\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt x }= \lim_{n\to \infty, h \to 0}\sum _{k=1}^{n}h(f(a+kh))$  (here: $f(x)= \frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ and $h = \dfrac{b-a}{n}$)

$= \lim_{n\to \infty} (h(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+2h}}...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+nh}}))$

Note that

$S= \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+2h}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+nh}}$

$\sum(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+nh}})< S <\sum(\frac{1}{\sqrt{nh}}) $

From squueze theorem $\lim _{h \to 0}S = \dfrac{n}{\sqrt a}$

So the initial riemann sum simplifies to:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{nh}{\sqrt a}$

Note that $nh = b-a$

$\implies $ the integral is equal to $\dfrac{b-a}{\sqrt a}$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What are f and h?  In the first line of your attempt, you have $h(f(a+kh)).$ It looks like you are evaluating the function h at the function f evaluated at a+kh, is this h the same as the function?

Comment: @gd1035 Edited.

Comment: So you seem to be letting $h\rightarrow{0}$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$ separately, but you cannot do this as $h$ depends on $n$. In the first line of your attempt, it should just have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ and not $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty,h\rightarrow{0}}$.

Comment: In the line for the squeeze theorem, you have the limit as h goes to 0, but h only goes to 0 when n goes to infinity (h is constant for each value of n).

Comment: Best option is to use the partition with points in geometric progression so that $x_k=ar^k$ and  $r^n=b/a$ and consider the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_{k})(x_k-x_{k-1})$$ The approach using $x_k=a+kh, nh=b-a$ is a bit tricky here and your working has many problems as explained in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

- $h$ is $n$-dependence, i.e. $$h=\dfrac{b-a}{n}$$
- $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\, dx =\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} hf(a+kh)$
- $x_{k}=a+kh$ for $k=0,1,\ldots, n$
- As $f(x)$ is decreasing in this case, the sandwich should be

$$\frac{\frac{b-a}{n}}{\sqrt{a+\frac{(b-a)(k+1)}{n}}}
< \int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
< \frac{\frac{b-a}{n}}{\sqrt{a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n}}}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\frac{b-a}{n}}{\sqrt{a+\frac{(b-a)(k+1)}{n}}}
< \int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
< \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\frac{b-a}{n}}{\sqrt{a+\frac{(b-a)k}{n}}}$$

- $b>a>0$
- Your summands are independent of the running index $k$ making your sandwich too loose.
- The sandwich should be **tight** enough so that both the lower and upper bounds converge to the same limit.
- There is no mathematical advantage of evaluating the integral by Riemann sum.  However, it'll be easy to find the sum by evaluating the integral.  Usually, the function itself should behave nice enough so that its series bounds can be evaluated by **standard series** (e.g. AP).
- See an example of evaluation of Riemann sum [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020567/working-with-square-roots/2020680#2020680) and also application of sandwich theorem in [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089018/verifying-riemann-sum/2089301#2089301) and also [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884025/prove-that-the-existence-of-the-solution/1884066#1884066).

Answer (score 0):

$${S_L} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + nh} }}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {a + \left( {b - a} \right)} }}}  = \frac{n}{{\sqrt b }} = \frac{{b - a}}{{\sqrt b h}}$$
$${S_R} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {nh} }}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{\sqrt {b - a} }}}  = \frac{n}{{\sqrt {b - a} }} = \frac{{\sqrt {b - a} }}{h}$$
Neither sum converges in the limit as $h \to 0$ (or, equivalently, as $n \to \infty$).

Comment: It's not nh - it is kh.

Comment: As written, the question says nh on line 4.  The sum doesn't indicate an index, which I took to be k, as it is on line 1.  If the n on line 4 is actually supposed to be a k (which is a possible interpretation), then SL equals S, making the squeeze theorem unneeded, and the left and right limits that lead to limiting value of S are just wrong.  To me, choosing the missing index as k rather than assuming a typo in what is provided appears to be the lesser of two evils.